# PHP Copy Issues

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to copy a file from my Plugin directory inside of Wordpress to the root directory of the Wordpress installation.  Here's my code:

```
$pluginfile = 'http://www.richmindonline.com/testenvironment/wp-content/plugins/malware
finder/process.php'; 

$urldest = 'http://www.richmindonline.com/testenvironment/process.php'; 

function copy(){  
global $pluginfile; global $urldest; 
copy($pluginfile,$urldest); } 
?>
```

I'm having some syntax issues or something, because it's not working at all.

I also have heard that I may need permissions to do this.  Is there a specific/generic example of how I could achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `copy` should work with a local file system in your case! not URLs. Provide a filesystem path as the origin and the destination.

Comment: I think I understand.....I think that's where I'm having problems too....the syntax.  Would you kindly write out an example and you can post with answer if you want

Comment: I do not know the real path to the files. Again, it should be something like `copy('/local/path/source.file', '/local/path2/destination.file');` The path could be relative to the location of the php file with that code, but it should not be an URL - only the path in the server's filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use URLs in your case, only paths to the file in the server's file system. In general it should be something like this (I do not state that it will work - everything depends on the locations of the files and changes made, for example, by mod_rewrite):

```
$pluginfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 
      '/testenvironment/wp-content/plugins/malwarefinder/process.php'; 

$urldest = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/testenvironment/process.php'; 

copy($pluginfile, $urldest);
```

Do not name your function as the built-in one.

Comment: Hi Cheery, the code definitely makes sense, but nothing happens at all when I add the code to the beginning of my plugin file.  I'm guessing it should go through the code right when I click on the actual plugin admin, but nonetheless no type of errors or results.  Any thoughts on this?

Comment: And document root is equivalent to public_html right?  I don't see any reason why these relative url's wouldn't work as you provided....hmmmm

Comment: `And document root is equivalent to public_html right` it is not always right - depends on the server's setup, aliases, mod_rewrite rules and so on. Check the output of the `phpinfo();` for all the server settings and pathes.